# using parameter's private data in constructor

Tags: c++11

I'm reading the shared_ptr's implement.here is the codes:

```
template<typename _Tp, _Lock_policy _Lp>
  class __shared_ptr
  {
public:
template<typename _Tp1, typename = _Convertible<_Tp1*>>
      __shared_ptr(const __shared_ptr<_Tp1, _Lp>& __r) noexcept
      : _M_ptr(__r._M_ptr), _M_refcount(__r._M_refcount)
      { }
  ...
private:
  ...
  __shared_count<_Lp>  _M_refcount;
  };
```

Question:

`_M_refcount` is a private data, why it can be used in `_M_refcount(__r._M_refcount)`
and do not have a error?

Comment: That's some code internal to a standard library implementation, it's not something you wrote. So what is *your* problem? What is the reason you show this code (which is probably working fine) and not yours (which probably have the problem)? Please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: The point of a constructor is to put an object into a valid state by initializing members. And like member functions it gets access to `private` members because otherwise it couldn't do what it is supposed to do.

Comment: @nwp `__r` is not the same class type as `*this`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because all the `__shared_ptr` templated classes are [made friends](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/da8dff89fa9398f04b107e388cb706517ced9505/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/shared_ptr_base.h#L1389) between each other:

> ```
> template<typename _Tp1, _Lock_policy _Lp1> friend class __shared_ptr;
> ```

---

If the above is not enough, here is some intro into access modifiers :)

a `private` member can be accessed by name only from within the same class.

E.g. this is ok:

```
class X
{
private:
    int a;

public:

   auto foo(X other)
   {
       return other.a; // OK
   }
};
```

When dealing with class templates you must realize that each class generated from the template is a different class:

```
template <class T> class X
{
private:
    int a;

public:
    template <class U>
    auto foo(X<U> other)
    {
        return other.a; // OK iff U == T
    }
};

X<int> xi;
X<bool> xb;

xi.foo(xb); // not OK
xi.foo(xi); // OK
```

In order for the above code to work for any `foo`, all the `X<T>` classes must be friends:

```
template <class U>
friend class X;
```

which is what is happening in `__shared_ptr` class template.